# Class defined Datatable, how to leave row [0] unchanged?

Tags: c#, dataset, rows

I add rows to the table configs like this, any form that i want

```
            DataRow row2 = DataAccess.Instance.configs.NewRow();
            row2["Nome"] = "abrirficheiro";
            row2["Valor"] = Convert.ToString(Variables.abrirficheiro);
            DataAccess.Instance.configs.Rows.Add(row2);
```

but i wanna keep the row at index 0 (the first one) untouched, any idea how it's done?
edit: i've been working around it for the past hour, still unsucessful

The table class code is like this

```
public sealed class DataAccess
{
    static readonly DataAccess instance = new DataAccess();


    //**adicionar tabelas aqui
    public DataTable configs { get; private set; }


    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static DataAccess()
    {
    }

    DataAccess()
    {

        this.configs = new DataTable("configs");


        TabelasSET.Tables.Add("configs");

        configs.Columns.Add("Nome");
        configs.Columns.Add("Valor");
    }

    public static DataAccess Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Solved: Modified the code this way

```
            DataRow row2 = DataAccess.Instance.configs.NewRow();
            row2["Nome"] = "abrirficheiro";
            row2["Valor"] = Convert.ToString(Variables.abrirficheiro);
            DataAccess.Instance.configs.Rows.InsertAt(row2, 2);

            DataAccess.Instance.configs.Rows.RemoveAt(1);


            //second set
            DataRow row3 = DataAccess.Instance.configs.NewRow();
            row3["Nome"] = "mantergravacao";
            row3["Valor"] = Convert.ToString(Variables.mantergravacao);
            DataAccess.Instance.configs.Rows.InsertAt(row3, 3);

            DataAccess.Instance.configs.Rows.RemoveAt(2);
```

And so on, basicaly, you gotta insert it first, then remove, i'm sure there are other ways but this has been working flawlessly

Answer (score 2):

```
  DataAccess.Instance.configs.Rows.InsertAt(row2,1)
```

Comment: "no overload method for insertAt", also i dont wanna add rows, i only wanna change the row [1] and row[2], leaving the [0] as it is @Harikant

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
DataRow row2 = DataAccess.Instance.configs.NewRow();
row2["Nome"] = "abc";
row2["Valor"] = "123";
DataAccess.Instance.configs.Rows.InsertAt(row2, 1);


DataRow row2 = DataAccess.Instance.configs.NewRow();
row2["Nome"] = "zyx";
row2["Valor"] = "789";
DataAccess.Instance.configs.Rows.InsertAt(row2, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you Ritesh but i solved it my own way, i will update the thread @Ritesh Khatri

Comment: please accpet my answer. if you satisfied with my answer

Comment: I'd really do, but i confess the harikant post helped more, when i came to see yours i had already solve it, and he was first. Sorry dude :(